# Does AJAX get requests (js) and "normal" access in browser differentiate when having same data retrieved?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, seo

Forgive me for my confusing title, but I hope I can make myself clear on this...

I have a question about SEO and javascript.

I've read that GET requests do get indexed by google. Right?

If I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="filter"></div>
<div id="products"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I update the filter and the products-divs with javascript (puts products in there based on selected filter).

If I for example have a filter that is (from javascript) requesting (with AJAX / GET-request) adress `http://domain/category-id/red` and the result from ajax result is:

```
<div id="products">red product1 in category-id</div>
<div id="products">red product2 in category-id</div>
<div id="products">red product3 in category-id</div>
<div id="products">red product4 in category-id</div>
```

Would this be the same from a googles perspective (I believe it would because javascript does a get request to the same data)?

```
I type in `http://domain/category-id/red`
```

in the browser and I'll get:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="filter"></div>
<div id="products">
<div id="products">red product1 in category-id</div>
<div id="products">red product2 in category-id</div>
<div id="products">red product3 in category-id</div>
<div id="products">red product4 in category-id</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Yes, I understand it might not be the best way to use javascript without having a fallback, but this is a question I would love if someone could clarify for me)

Or would it matter at all? I've just read that internal links arent that important!? (Is that really true?) but external are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google does process JavaScript now](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) so this content *should* be indexed by them without issue. How the other search engines handle this is another question.

As far as internal links vs external links., internal links are helpful for SEO. Their importance is as debatable as anything else, but they do help SEO. It's probably one of the reasons Wikipedia does so well. Their internal linking is as close to perfect as it gets.

Comment: Thanks. That absolulety cleard things up for me. Almost anyway. It seems that Google has solved it, but it seems like a "beta" version of it... ...that is under discussion... I would say Google is the only search engine that "matters" nowadays anyway - if you're talking about getting traffic to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Google's JS parsing abilities are not consistent.

If you want to know what code Google reads on a page, use Google Webmaster Tools (a great free service they offer webmasters) and use the "Fetch as Google" feature.

Once a file is fetched, you can also submit it to Google's index from here.

[image: Fetch page]

[image: Check page's code]

[image]

A similar, but less accurate option, is to check the Google cache version of a page (cache:mydomain.com/anypage) and then click on the "Text-only version", then view the source HTML.

Chances are very good that any elements missing in this view are not available to Google's spiders.

The advantages of this second method is that you can check sites that do not belong to you, and there is no need for a Webmaster Tools account, but I recommend that any webmaster that relies on Google traffic to take advantage of this feature-rich service.

[image: Google Cache]